# ASP.NET is it possible to use Session & HttpContext.Application in a library

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have the following code in a HttpGet method in a Controller

```
Session["var1"] = "someval1";
HttpContext.Application["var2"] = "someval2";
```

I wish to put away this code in a library [dll] so that in the library I have

```
// Inside DLL Library  
// namespace MyNS, class MyCl

public void InitVars()
{
    Session["var1"] = "someval1";
    HttpContext.Application["var2"] = "someval2";
}
```

And the call this from my controller Get method

// In controller class HttpGet

```
    InitVars();
```

How do I access the Session & the Application objects in the Library

I get the errors

> The name Session does not exist in the current context
>
> The name HttpContext does not exist in the current context

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to open up the code library .csproj in Visual Studio and [set a reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) to [System.Web.dll](https://forums.asp.net/t/1843409.aspx?Where+is+System+Web+dll+located+) and the same code will work in the DLL.

You can get a reference to the current `HttpContext` using the following code:

```
var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
```

after which you can simply call

```
context.Session["var1"] = "someval1";
context.Application["var2"] = "someval2";
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
void InitLogin(System.Web.HttpSessionStateBase Session, 
             System.Web.HttpApplicationStateBase Application)
{
    Session["var1"] = "someval1";
    Application["var2"] = "someval2";
}
```

and call it as

```
InitVars(Session, Application);
```

Comment: You could also access them statically via `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session` and `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application`.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I access the Session & the Application objects in the Library

Don't do it directly, you'll couple your code.  I recommend using the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).  Something like this (untested):

Class Library:

```
public interface IStorage
{
  T GetSession<T>(string key);
  void SetSession<T>(string key, T value);
  T GetGlobal<T>(string key);
  void SetGlobal<T>(string key, T value);
}

public void InitVars(IStorage storage)
{
  storage.SetSession("var1", "someval1");
  storage.SetGlobal("var2", "somval2");
}
```

Web App:

```
public class WebStorage : IStorage
{
  public T GetSession<T>(string key)
  {
    var result = Session[key] as T;
    return result;
  }
  public void SetSession<T>(string key, T value)
  {
    Session[key] = value;
  }
  // etc with Global
}


InitVars(new WebStorage);
```

Now you have no dependencies on any web classes.  If down the road you decide to use asp.net core (which has no HttpContext.Current etc etc) you can easily modify your WebStorage class without having to change your class library.